# How can I edit makefile to change Doxyfile settings?

Tags: makefile, doxygen

I have the below code in my makefile. The makefile generates a Doxyfile with standard configurations. I want to change the UML_LOOK tag to YES and GENERATE_TREEVIEW to YES without having to edit the file manually. Is there a way of passing commands to the makefile so it does the job itself?

```
doc:
    doxygen -g Doxyfile
    doxygen Doxyfile
    rm -rf latex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `sed` commands to edit the `Doxyfile`in place just after its generation:

```
sed -i '/UML_LOOK.*=/s/^.*$/UML_LOOK = YES/' Doxyfile
sed -i '/GENERATE_TREEVIEW.*=/s/^.*$/GENERATE_TREEVIEW = YES/' Doxyfile
```

And if you don't need LaTeX output, you can change the GENERATE_LATEX option the same way instead of removing latex directory afterwards.